# how to develop LeGall 5/3 filter for reversible watermarking?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet-transform

I want to implement a reversible image watermarking that use IWT transform and filter 5/3.
at first I thing this filter is cdf 5.3 that it is in matlab. but after running the code I found out that this is not true and filter 5/3 is different. after search that I had, I found this filter is legall 5/3 that used in JPEG2000. now I should implement filter legall 5/3 at first and then choose subband HL1 to embedding my data for watermarking. I am a little confused how to implement this filter and use of HL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LeGall 5/3 wavelet (CDF 5/3) is named as bior2.2 in MATLAB.
The [`dwt2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html) command with `'bior2.2'` argument performs the two-dimensional CDF 5/3 wavelet decomposition:

```
[LL,HL,LH,HH] = dwt2(x,'bior2.2');
```

This returns the requested HL subband. However, you probably do not want to use it.

As you have mentioned, an integer-to-integer approximation of CDF 5/3 wavelet is also used in the JPEG 2000 standard for a lossless compression. This is possible thanks to lifting scheme. In MATLAB, the integer CDF 5/3 lifting scheme is named cdf2.2. Thus, the following commands are what you probably looking for:

```
ls = liftwave('cdf2.2');
[LL,HL,LH,HH] = lwt2(x,ls);
```

See [`lwt2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/lwt2.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot.I have an other question. I am doing reversible watermarking.at the end of  embedding I should do ilwt and convert the image to uint8. it create distortion and its not acceptable. what should I do?